# Mapping a JOIN to a class structure in Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, join

I have a piece of code that retrieves products through EntityFramework. Each product includes a list of ProductElements:

```
            var products = dbContext.Product.Include(p => p.ProductElement)
                .Where( // conditions
```

We need to add a computed field to the result, that requires some processing on DB side and is beyond the capabilities of an Entity Framework query. This whole select was moved into a table valued DB function, which returns the same result, but with the computed column added. However, as this is SQL, the relationship between Product and ProductElement is now a JOIN. So where before I had one Product with a list of 37 ProductElement objects, now I have 37 rows with the same ProductId (and Product data), one for each related ProductElement.

I suppose I could create a DTO that exactly matches the rows returned by the function, and then do the grouping and generating of ProductElement objects manually. But I'm hoping is there's a way to set things up so that EF does this for me. Is there?